# Cannot create trajectory from message. It does not contain the expected joints

Tags: ros, gazebo, arm-controller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Command I run in terminal:

```
$ roslaunch tiago_gazebo tiago_gazebo.launch public_sim:=true robot:=steel

$ rostopic pub /arm_controller/command trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectory "header:
  seq: 0
  stamp:
    secs: 0
    nsecs: 0
  frame_id: ''
joint_names:
- 'arm_1_joint'
points:
- positions: [0.5]
  velocities: [0]
  accelerations: [0]
  effort: [0]
  time_from_start: {secs: 1, nsecs: 0}"
```

Result from terminal:

```
[ERROR] [1493904854.162621476, 91.554000000]: Cannot create trajectory from message. It does not contain the expected joints.
```

However I can see from gazebo simulator there is `arm_1_joint` by expanding the model of `tiago_steel`.

How could I solve this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261081/cannot-create-trajectory-from-message.-it-does-not-contain-the-expected-joints./) by [waschbaer](https://answers.ros.org/users/30263/waschbaer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2017-05-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The controller you are using is [this](https://github.com/pal-robotics/tiago_simulation/blob/indigo-devel/tiago_controller_configuration_gazebo/config/joint_trajectory_controllers.yaml).

if `allow_partial_joints_goal: True` is not set your have to specify all of the joints in de arm_controller.

Like:

```
$ rostopic pub -1 /arm_controller/command trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectory "header:
  seq: 0
  stamp:
     secs: 0
     nsecs: 0
  frame_id: ''
joint_names: [arm_1_joint, arm_2_joint, arm_3_joint, arm_4_joint, arm_5_joint, arm_6_joint, arm_7_joint]
points:
- positions: [0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  time_from_start: {secs: 1, nsecs: 0}"
```

---

Originally posted by [msabur](https://answers.ros.org/users/30425/msabur/) with karma: 98 on 2017-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prashanthi tata](https://answers.ros.org/users/38936/prashanthi-tata/) on 2018-12-10**:
I have sent joint values from csv file yet i get this error. Please help. I have also set the above constraint true

PS: Only joint 1 and 2 of my robot can be detected